# Audio Equalisation

Tags: windows-10, audio, equations

While using my computer, I noticed that when one program makes a loud noise, all other sounds are softened.

(e.g. Playing music and and an email notification comes in.)

Is there a way to disable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click sound icon on taskbar and choose `Playback devices`. Right click on your default sound output device go to `Advanced` tab uncheck both options in `Exclusive Mode` section.